# Why does GCC use two instructions for incrementing a value?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, intel, disassembly

Why does GCC use

```
lea eax,[ebp-4]
inc DWORD PTR [eax]
```

when

```
inc DWORD PTR [ebp-4]
```

should theoretically do the same?

Comment: What is your actual programming problem where you think the answer involves the distinction between the two sequences above? They are equivalent.

Comment: @RaymondChen I am genuinely curious as to why this happens as well. I very highly doubt it helps or harms performance, but it's interesting that GCC would do that.

Comment: Did you request optimization? Failing to do so tells the compiler that you don't care how good the generated code is. Please show us the exact source code you're using (and tell us what language it is), and the command line you used to compile it.

Comment: There are any number of reasons why the compiler might choose the two-instruction form. If the variable is frequently-accessed, reusing the EA reduces code size, if you are optimizing for minimum size. But it is of no practical consequence and is therefore not suitable for SO, which is for practical programming problems.

Comment: @RaymondChen What? Since when does every stackoverflow question have to be practical and have practical use? I don't see "impractical" as a close reason

Comment: "[Get answers to practical, detailed questions](http://stackoverflow.com/about)." "What kind of questions should I not ask here? [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)."